# A question in java.lang.Integer internal code

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

While looking in the code of the method:

[Integer.toHexString](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29)

I found the following code :

```
public static String toHexString(int i) {
    return toUnsignedString(i, 4);
}

private static String toUnsignedString(int i, int shift) {
    char[] buf = new char[32];
    int charPos = 32;
    int radix = 1 << shift;
    int mask = radix - 1;
    do {
        buf[--charPos] = digits[i & mask];
        i >>>= shift;
    } while (i != 0);

    return new String(buf, charPos, (32 - charPos));
}
```

The question is, in toUnsignedString, why we create a char arr of 32 chars?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

32 characters is how much you need to represent an `int` in binary (base-2, `shift` of 1, used by `toBinaryString`).

It could be sized exactly, but I guess it has never made business sense to attempt that optimisation.

Answer (score 2):

Because that method is also called by `toBinaryString()`, and an `int` is up to 32 digits in binary.

Answer (score 1):

Because the max value for an int in Java is : 2^31 - 1

Comment: aha, thanks, I forget it. It seemed to be very dump Question.

Thanks all guyz.